# SQL - Counting Returned Records

Tags: sql

I'm building a stored procedure. This stored procedure needs to insert a record if a record with a specific value does not exist. If the value does exist, I need to update the record. The problem I'm having is determining if a record with the given value exists or not. I am using the following code:

```
DECLARE @record1ID as char(36)
SET @record1ID = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM Person WHERE [Role]='Manager')

DECLARE @record2ID as char(36)
SET @record2ID = (SELECT TOP 1 d.ID FROM Department d WHERE d.[ManagerID]=@record1ID)

-- If @record2ID is set update record, otherwise add record 
-- how do I setup this if/else statement?
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IF (EXISTS YOUR_SELECT)
BEGIN ...
```

or

```
IF (@record2ID IS NULL) 
BEGIN ...
```

or use `select count(*)` instead of selecting a value

Answer (score 1):

If this were a SQL Server as it looks like, you could do a count like this:

declare @rec_counter as int

set @rec_counter = 0

select @rec_counter = count(*) FROM Department d WHERE d.[ManagerID]=@record1

if (@rec_counter > 0)

begin

```
-- do whatever here
```

end